# How can I expose local variables defined in anonymous function to the global space?

Tags: javascript

I have a case where variables are defined inside an self-executing anonymous function. I want to expose them to the global space so I can use `foo` and `bar` after the anonymous function returns.

```
(function () {
    var foo = 123;
    var bar = function () { /* ... */ };
})();
```

A problem is that I cannot simply do `window.foo = 123` or `SomeExistingGlobalObject.foo = 123` to expose it because *I do not know what comes in inside the anonymous function in advance*. The content inside the function is dynamically generated.

I tried returning another self-executing function from that function, but that did not work, either. Is this possible?

Comment: did you try using arguments inside the anonymouse function

Comment: I cannot put arguments inside the function, either.

Comment: Then no. This is not possible. They are local to that function.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [revealing module pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript):

```
var module = (function () {
  var foo = 123;
  var bar = function () {
    console.log('Hallo');
  };
  return { foo: foo, bar: bar }
})();

console.log(module.foo); // 123
module.bar(); // Hallo
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9qvt0h2/)

Comment: Thanks, but this requires me to know that foo and bar exist inside the function. I don't even know the number or the name of the variables inside that function.

Comment: If necessary you can get the properties of the module with `Object.keys(module)` - an array with elements `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem you're having now. No, it's not possible. Those variables are local to that function. If you can't change it you're basically stuck.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. Well, thanks for your answer, still.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate syntax than @Andy you can also go

```
var module = (function () {
  var fnpublic = {};
  var fubar = 123;

  fnpublic.foo = 123;
  fnpublic.bar = function () {
    console.log('Hallo');
  };

  return fnpublic;
})();

module.foo; // -> 123
module.bar(); // -> "hallo"
module.fubar; // -> undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

Other elegant way is to do:

```
(function() {

  var that = this;   // Pass window global scope
  var private_1 = 1; // Create private variable

  // Create method to expose
  var method = function(number) {
    alert(number + private_1);
  };

  // Expose global_obj 
  that.global_obj = {
    alert: method
  };

 }.call(this));


 // In console now you may type
 global_obj.alert(5);
```

You may have private method as well.